# Woocommerce site load issue with multi level product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce installation with variable products. Basically iits a catalogue that users can view and place bulk order.

There are over 50K products (with variation). There are nested categories like Tshirt (Polo Tshirt, round neck Tshirt, Sport tee, womens T-shrt etc) and there are other categories that is not nested for instance Head gear or bags.

Pages (products) with nested categories are not loading properly. Single level categories are working fine.

For multilevel categories, the site is taking 5-10 minutes to load and that’s like terrible. In fact if I test the page speed on google, it times out.

I have already checked image size, using W3 Total Cache and Max CDN (premium) so that does not sound like an issue.

The issue is primarily with multi level categories.  So I guess it’s the woocommerce issue and not related to hardware, hosting or something like that
I am using latest version of woocommerce.
I am using **storefront-childtheme**

These are the active plugins (if it helps)
Contact Form 7,
Cookie Consent, 
Photo Gallery, 
Product Categories Designs for WooCommerce,
Quick Product Image Upload,
Regenerate Thumbnails,
Ultimate WooCommerce Brands,
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore,
W3 Total Cache,
WooCommerce,
WooCommerce - Store Exporter,
WooCommerce Auto Category Thumbnails,
WooCommerce PDF & Print,
WooSwatches - Woocommerce Color or Image Variation Swatches,
Wordfence Security,
WP All Import - WooCommerce Add-On Pro  ,
WP All Import Pro,
WP Super Cache  ,
YITH WooCommerce Zoom Magnifier,
Yoast SEO,
Zoom Image,

Do you guys have experienced similar issue and if yes, how did you got it resolved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this GitHub discussion -> https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/4644 it has solutions around your problem

Comment: Hi Clowin, looked at the thread..but unable to figure-out anything. I am still at it. Thanks